# General forecasting formula for ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)s

Tags: forecasting, arima

what is general forecasting equation for sARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)s.?

I wrote this equation, can someone confirm if it is a correct one?

$\overline{y}_{t+m}=\frac{ (\varphi_{1}y_{t} + \varphi_{2}y_{t-1}+...+ \varphi_{p}y_{t-p+m})(\phi_{1}y_{t} + \phi_{2}y_{t-s}+...+ \phi_{P}y_{t-P+m})}{(\theta_{1}e_{t}-\theta_{2}e_{t-1}-...-\theta_{q}e_{t-q+m})(\Theta_{1}e_{t}-\Theta_{2}e_{t-s}-...-\Theta_{Q}e_{t-Q+m})}$

If not, can someone correct it?

I need it in a form 
$\overline{y}_{t+m}= ....$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) It seems that you are trying to write the infinite moving-average represenation of the ARIMA model, in which case the lag operator should be applied to the innovations $e_t$ not to the series $y_t$. A more natural equation for the forecasts is the equation of the ARIMA model itself; simply move the indices $m$ observations forward, no need for the fraction of polynomials; it will look more like $y_{t+1} = \phi y_t + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$. 2) You are not accounting for $d$ and $D$. 3) The indices should go $t+m-1,t+m-2,...,t+m-p$ and for the seasonal $t+m-s,t+m-2s,...,t+m-Ps$.

Comment: Yo may want to add the tag [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to your question.